# Rails migration stops & hangs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake, rails-migrations

I have the following migration:

```
class AddHyphenatedNameToMenus < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :menus, :hyphenated_name, :string, null: false, required: true
  end

  def down
    remove_column :menus, :hyphenated_name
  end
end
```

The rails migration stops mysteriously and hangs.

```
$ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
==  AddHyphenatedNameToMenus: migrating =======================================
-- add_column(:menus, :hyphenated_name, :string, {:null=>false, :required=>true})
```

On pressing 'ctrl+c' I get the following error trace:

```
undefined method `result' for Interrupt:Interrupt/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@abc/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1147:in `translate_exception'
```

I am unable to find the reason for the same. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what's in the migration?

Comment: @sevenseacat I have updated my question, pls chk.